# How to get height of UITextField in viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm creating a `UITextField` in `viewDidAppear` and i'd like to use its height to draw a line underneath the textfield using a `CALayer`. As expected, the height of the textfield is zero since it hasn't been drawn yet!

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    setUpTextField()
    drawUnderLine()
}

func drawUnderLine(){
    let bottomLine = CALayer()
    bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x: textField.bounds.origin.x, y: textField.bounds.origin.y + textField.bounds.size.height + 2, width: self.view.bounds.width - 100, height: 1.0)
    textField.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)
}
```

My way around this is to draw a line using a `UIView` and setting the top anchor of the line equal to the bottom anchor of the textfield. However, I'd like to know how to resolve this for future situations.

Comment: did you call `addSubLayer` ? In addition, you may should set `bottomLine's frame` inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: @TungVuDuc I tried that and its drawing two lines - one line is drawn at a y when the textfield height is zero and then another line is drawn with the right y position

Comment: Try make `bottomLine` as global layer instead, and set its frame inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews `

Comment: @TungVuDuc Not sure what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    setUpTextField()
    drawUnderLine()
}

let bottomLine = CALayer()
func drawUnderLine(){
    textField.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x: textField.bounds.origin.x, y:
        textField.bounds.origin.y + textField.bounds.size.height + 2, width:
        self.view.bounds.width - 100, height: 1.0)
}
```

Comment: ahhh that makes sense!